# Загружать изображения в приложение с сервера через API

Tags: изображения, android, eclipse, графика

Пишу приложение под Android на Eclipse. задача такова: приложение должно загружать изображения в приложение с сервера через API. Вопросы:

- Как реализовать?
- Какой элемент необходимо использовать для этой цели?

Gallery порядком устарел, да и при большом количестве изображений это неудобно. GridView поддерживает только сжатые размеры. Так же, при нажатие на загруженное изображение, должна быть возможность открыть её в полном размере с комментариями и тд, то есть как диалоговое окно. Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Gridview, у которого установлен onItemClickListener. А картинку открывать в новом фрагменте.

Comment: так вот проблема в том, что само поле GridView приложение отображает, а картинок нету. пустота.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я рекомендую использовать [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) или [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Для kotlin можно использовать [coil](http://hhttps://github.com/coil-kt/coil)

Answer (score 4):

Для таких целей я использовал [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), в семплах есть пример как в [Gridview](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/sample/src/com/nostra13/example/universalimageloader/ImageGridActivity.java) загружать и при нажатии открывать и листать [ViewPager](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/sample/src/com/nostra13/example/universalimageloader/ImagePagerActivity.java).

Comment: спасибо огромное!